# The process cannot access the file <filepath> because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, stream, asmx, filestream

I'm upload big files dividing its on chunks(small parts) on my ASMX webservice(asmx doesn't support streaming, I not found another way):

```
bool UploadChunk(byte[] bytes, string path, string md5)
{
      ...
      using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempPath, FileMode.Append) )
      {   
            fs.Write( bytes, 0, bytes.Length );
      }
      ...
      return status;
}
```

but on some files after ~20-50 invokes I catch this error:
 The process cannot access the file  because it is being used by another process.

 I suspect that this related with Windows can't realize the file. Any idea to get rid of this boring error?

**EDIT**

the requests executes sequentially and synchronously

**EDIT2**

client code looks like:

```
_service.StartUpload(path);

...
do
{
..
bool status = _service.UploadChunk(buf, path, md5);
if(!status)return Status.Failed;
..
}
while(bytesRead > 0);

_service.CheckFile(path, md5);
```

Comment: AppendMode is not enough when chunks are coming in in parallel

Comment: chunks are not coming in parallel. It comes sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

Each request is handled independently. The process still accessing the file may be the previous request.

In general, you should use file transfer protocols to transfer files. ASMX is not good for that.

And, I presume you have a good reason to not use WCF?

Comment: I send requests sequentially. ASMX due the requirements. This also provides send some files(but not all:() even bigger than 5 GB.

Comment: @2x: you may be sending sequentially, but that doesn't mean the requests are handled sequentially! Also, is that the only access to the file in your code? Do you ever rename it, move it, delete it?

Comment: I catch the status of last request and if it returns ok I send next request. I also calculate MD5 of result file in the end of all requests.

Comment: @2x: yeah, ok, since they are single requests and not streaming. However, since the path is passed in the request, is it possible that a different client is also trying to upload to the same file?

Comment: No, only I sended and only from my local computer to same computer. Also only one client can start upload for concrete file.

Answer (score 0):

Use WhoLockMe at the moment the error occurs to check who is using the file. You could put the application into debug mode and hold the break point to do this. In all probability it will be your process.

Also try adding a delay after each transfer (and before the next) to see if it helps. Maybe your transfers are too fast and the stream is still in use or being flushed when the next transfer comes in.

Answer (score -1):

Option 1: Get the requirements changed so you don't have to do this using ASMX.  WCF supports a streaming model that I'm about to experiment with, but it should be much more effective for what you want.

Option 2: Look into WSE 3.0.  I haven't looked at it much, but I think it extends ASMX web services to support things like DIME and MTOM which are designed for transferring files so that may help.

Option 3:  Set the system up so that each call writes a piece of the file into a different filename, then write code to rejoin everything at the end.

Comment: -1: WSE is obsolete. Don't use it, and certainly don't suggest anyone else use it.

Comment: If you're forced to use old technology you're forced to use old technology.  There's a reason I suggested getting the requirements changed first.

Answer (score -1):

use this for creating a file

if you want to append something then add `FileMode.Append`

```
var filestreama = new FileStream(name, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```